# Selecting a value from output of ps -eaf

Tags: shell, kill, ps

Suppose i want to select 6547 from this output of "ps -eaf" 
command, how do i do it? I want to select that value and give it to "kill" command to kill that process.

```
root      6547     1  0 Aug07 ?        00:00:00 
root     14805     2  0 Aug07 ?        00:00:00 
root     17443 30043  0 16:21 pts/0    00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have to write a small shell script - which will basically contain below option -

```
    pidList=`ps -eaf | awk ' print $2'`  
    for pid in pidList  
    cmd="kill -9 $pid"  
    `$cmd`
```

Now based on your critieria (like process name, user etc) you can take action for that specific process. So the jist here is to use `awk` command to get your exact column.

Comment: It worked with few changes:`ps -eaf | grep 'processname*'  | awk '{print $2" "$1  "\n"}' |  grep 'username*' | awk '{print $1}'` gave me exact value. I suppose you forgot {} in awk

Comment: Try to use ps with -U option if you need it for only specific user. That would be even better!